# RecyclerView not getting touch events because there is another LinearLayout above (sometimes)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-touch-event

I have a `RecyclerView` that gets touch events.
Everything works fine, but, when I make `Visibility.Visible` a `LinearLayout` (`android:clickable="true"`)  above the `Recyclerview`, and later I make it `Visibility.Gone` .Then the `recyclerView` does not gets the touch events.
What can I do?

```
    mTipContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTipContainer.setClickable(false);
    mTipContainer.setOnClickListener(null);
```

**`tip_container`**  is the problematic Layout, that swallows `RecyclerView` touch events when `visibility.visible`, and even when once shown is visibility.gone.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:elevation="7dp">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
       >
    </include>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/contenedor" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#313131"
    android:id="@+id/tip_container"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tip_drawable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/tip_minutos"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tip_close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_close"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/tip_boton_continuar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"

        fancy:fb_textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="#00000000"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="@color/BotonVerdeFocus"
        fancy:fb_radius="0dp"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#ffffff"
        fancy:fb_text="Continuar"
        fancy:fb_textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

        android:visibility="visible"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post some code..So that it easy to address the issue

Comment: is too much code ...

Comment: set clickable false when you set visibilty.gone

Comment: see edits please, i tried it

Comment: this is not complete xml pls post complete xml

Comment: Try to add your recyclerview at the bottom and check!

Comment: That was the solution!!! I just tried it, the problem was the order inside container of both Layouts <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your RecyclerView tag at the bottom of the file and check!